# The Custom UIMenuItem is too wide in IOS5

Tags: ios5, uimenucontroller

I have a UIWebView in my app,and it can perform the UIMenuController. And I add a Custom UIMenuItem to the UIMenuController(like "google it").
The code I add the UIMenuItem is:

```
UIMenuItem *searchItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"google it" action:@selector(searchWithSelectedText)];
    [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:searchItem]];
    [searchItem release];
```

Now,the custom UIMenuItem can be shown and do the right thing after clicked.
But in ios5,the UIMenuItem is too wide when it be shown.

Can the custom UIMenuItem be set shorter like the system items?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the new system style, I don't think you can customize it.